# picking elements from non static arrays so that each element is unique in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a way to efficiently pick elements from dependent arrays so that I get unique elements if possible.  And if not, keep as high of a uniquness as possible.

This is for a meal planner so I am trying to have as many unique meals as possible.  A simplified version of what I am doing is like this.

2000 calorie base goal
Breakfast is 15% - 30% of target for the day.  This means I can pick items from a database that are within this range.  As this is the first meal every day will be the same.  In this case 300-600 calorie meals.

When lunch is determined, the range would be dependent on the previous values so I would get a different array of possible meals for each day.

After this dinner would be calculated again based on what was picked for breakfast and lunch.

So this means that whatever meal I pick influences the data found in the other arrays so I don't know what the data is until a choice has been made.  I am trying to figure out how to achieve this while avoiding brute force if at all possible.

For now the numbers are not so high but I would like this to be scaleable.  At some point going through every possible combination when there are thousands of items in the array wouldn't be possible.

Next best I thought would be a sort of "smart" brute force where it fully determined a day.  It then tries to determine the 2nd day.  If it gets a duplicate it reattempts some combination until it gets a unique element for each of the meals.  However I run into an issue when it is impossible to create a unique day.  If it is impossible then I need to order it in such a way that the duplicates are as far apart as possible.

I am not even sure how to search for this kind of question if it has been asked before.  Is there any better way to do this other than just randomly trying until it succeeds? A final issue I have thought of was when I tried to do this and pick the least common choices first so that I had the best shot of making a unique day as possible.  For example if there were a total of 10 total meals to pick from and a day had the only instance where it was possible, to always pick that first.  However this runs into the issue of uneven distribution which will mess up analytics I plan on doing on this.  These should be as random as possible.

Here is what I am trying to achieve

Assuming I start with breakfast I can easily figure out if duplicates are needed or not

```
allBreakfasts = [1,3,5,6,8,10,12,17]
```

I got 8 possible meals and I can randomly assign them to each day without problem.

then lunches would be an array for each day so it could be:

```
Lunch[0] = [1,2,3,4]
Lunch[1] = [1,3,4]
Lunch[2] = [1,2,3,4,5]
Lunch[3] = [5,6,7,8,9,10]
Lunch[4] = [1,3,5]
Lunch[5] = [4,5]
Lunch[6] = [1,4]
```

I would need to organize these as randomly as possible across the days.  But if I just went in sequence I would likely run into an issue.  In this case there is no possible way to organize them with a unique meal in each day but the best I can see is [2,3,5,6,3,4,1] only a single repeat and spaced as far as possible. Basically looking for some type of optimization algorithm.  It will get even more complex for dinner as I need to pick correct options for lunch to allow for as great of a flexibility for dinner as certain choices could lock me into sub optimal scenarios that could be avoided

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
day = [/* all 2000 calos */];
morning = takeFrom(day, 25) ;
afternoon = takeFrom(day, 40):
night = day;
```

Comment: I can get the meals to work out pretty well, that is pretty similar to what I am doing.  I assign a ratio to each meal and then figure out what meals work in that.  Issue is I can get duplicate meals.  So for example I pick L1 for lunch on day 1 and then L1 is picked again on day 2.  It works fine mathematically but not in real life.  I can't just say L1 is no longer allowed because there might be only 6 possible meals and L1 has to repeat once

Comment: If the collection is not limited to a day, then just collect into array items instead of variables. The biggest complexity for me here is trying to interprete your explanations accurately. You can always prevent duplicates when you can clearly define what you do not want to duplicate...

Comment: I can't know there will be enough elements to limit.  I can't exclude an element in the next days array because it might be necessary to have duplicates.  And if I have duplicates they would need to appear in a specific order

Comment: Then you just need to define the order clearly and the rest will be easy...

Comment: Not sure I follow I don't know the order until after it is complete.  And some choices that I make earlier in the process might be wrong.  Picking meals [1,3,8,14,17,20,22] for lunch might yield a dinner set that has only 6 choices.  However if I would use 23 instead of 22 I could have 7 unique dinners.  I won't know what dinners are available until after I pick the lunch meals.  The only way I am seeing is brute force.  Pick the lunches, if they don't work try another set

Comment: You have not been able to get your message across to me. The best thing now is for you to post 1 or 2 example brute force you are talking about (breakfast to dinner;; 3 or more days). Then we can see how to make a general form out of it. I think that is what you seek; right?